# Could applying an anaconda choke to a turtled opponent be mistaken for a neck crank in gi BJJ?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, sport, chokes

I am worried about getting disqualified for applying an anaconda choke to an opponent in the turtle position (on all fours). I know this choke is allowed in no-gi, but will referees think I'm doing a neck-crank if I try it in gi?

Comment: Do you mean under IBJJF rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely legal in all GI based competitions that I've seen.  As long as it's not mistaken for a neck crank (doubt it - but you never know how terrible the ref is) it should be fine.  I've seen people DQ'd for baratoplata's which were mistaken for a bicep slicer.

Comment: Mike the baratoplata was my next question. You answered it :p

Answer (score 2):

Anaconda, Brabo, D'Arce style chokes are harder to pull off in gi because friction acts against getting the crucial deep arm position. But there's no reason for them to be illegal. It isn't a neck crank. That doesn't stop a referee from thinking, wrongly, that it is a neck crank, but I haven't heard of that being common.

Answer (score 1):

As per the IBJJF's current ruleset, chokes involving spinal locks (i.e. neck cranks) are **legal** at all adult belt divisions:

[image]

- [IBJJF Rule Book (v5.2) | Technical Fouls](https://ibjjf.com/books-videos)

So as long as there is clearly a choke in the technique (e.g. D'Arce, Anaconda, kata-gatame) it's valid. The ruleset provides examples of illegal spinal locks *without* a choke:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is legal in GI based competition.

Like Mike66350216 said, it "could" be mistaken for a neck crank, but most referees are aware of this.